# 40kHz ultrasonic transducer - datasheet gives capacitive load at 1kHz. What is it at 40kHz?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, ultrasound

A hopefully simple question, the [datasheet](http://www.prowave.com.tw/pdf/txall.pdf) for a 25kHz ultrasonic transducer gives the capacitance load at 1kHz. What is it at 25kHz?

I've been calculating the current using

I = fCVpp

Where f is driving frequency,
C is capacitance (I've been assuming its the same as 1kHz.) Vpp is peak to peak driving voltage.

Is this a reasonable assumption for designing an amplifier?

Comment: If C vs f is not in the datasheet we can't tell you. You drive most transducers at their resonant frequency what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the title you ask about 40 kHz but in the text you only mention 25 kHz. Since the transducers from the datasheet are 25 kHz transducers I will assume that 40 kHz was a typo and ignore it. A 25 kHz transducer would not work very well at 40 kHz. If you need 40 kHz, get a 40 kHz transducer.

*Is this a reasonable assumption for designing an amplifier?*

No, look at the plot of the **impedance** over frequency. Note how the impedance changes roughly a factor **10** within about 2 kHz. That's because such a transducer is also a mechanical resonator. It resonates at around 25 kHz which causes the steep changes in impedance around that frequency.

The capacitance of the transducer is stated at 1 kHz because that is "far away" from the 25 kHz it is supposed to be used at.

Here's an **electrical model** of a transducer:

[image]

At the low frequency of 1 kHz you'd only measure the value of \$C_e\$, the influence of \$L_m\$, \$C_m\$ and the \$R_m\$ resistors is so small at 1 kHz that we can ignore them.

But at 25 kHz it is a different story! Then the circuit elements that we can ignore at 1 kHz now have a **significant** influence on the impedance of the transducer.

However, I think you're overthinking this as fortunately the impedance of a transducer is quite high (I see 1 kohm or more in the plots) near the resonance frequency so it is "easy" to design an amplifier / driver for that.

Start with looking up some circuits which are used to drive a transducer. Ask yourself why it is done like that.

Do you think that you will need a high current and/or high voltage to drive a transducer?

[source](https://www.intechopen.com/books/advances-in-ceramics-electric-and-magnetic-ceramics-bioceramics-ceramics-and-environment/modeling-and-identification-of-parameters-the-piezoelectric-transducers-in-ultrasonic-systems)

Comment: many thanks for the detailed response and useful source. I've only driven transducers with a square wave but needed accurate phase control which was easier in analogue. Most sine wave drives seem orientated to high voltage and use transformers. I found [this] (https://www.techbriefs.com/component/content/article/tb/techbriefs/semiconductors-and-ics/5615) circuit which seemed overly complex for my application and I didn't need the oscillator.